# What is training

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, training

I'm a newbie on deep learning and I have a simple question.

I'm reading some article about the neural network. It says that people created a simple neural network named perceptron. And this network can't solve a very simple question: exclusive or.

I think it's because I don't know how to train a neural network or how to set the weights for a neural network.

Could you describe the process of training for perceptron with the example AND: `0 & 0 = 0  1 & 0 = 0  0 & 1 = 0  1 & 1 = 1`
With such a training, how do the weights in perceptron look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the Site!

Assuming that simple neural network means **Single layer Perceptron**.
I think you need to understand this, a simple neural network with a single hidden layer cannot solve an XOR problem. As they are not **Linearly Separable**.

To overcome this, we use **Multi-Layer Perceptron**, you can go through this [Link](http://lab.fs.uni-lj.si/lasin/wp/IMIT_files/neural/nn04_mlp_xor/) for better understanding.

Regarding your question with respect weights in Neural Network for solving XOR, please go through this [lecture](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/courses/ITNP4B/lectures/kms/4-MLP.pdf), this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apPiZd-qnZ8), in the video they explain you how the weights are adjusted in every iteration before getting the solution.

If you are stuck somewhere do let me know, will try to help you!

Other links:

[Link-1](http://www.philbrierley.com/main.html?code/bpproof.html&code/codeleft.html)

Another link suggested by @Yves : [Link](http://toritris.weebly.com/)

Comment: I've found another link, I paste it here for other newbies: http://toritris.weebly.com/

Comment: Your welcome!, Hope your doubts are cleared!

Comment: Updated the answer, appended the link you suggested.